# Quarkus + Swagger UI + Keycloak

Tags: swagger, openid-connect, quarkus

I would like to use my Keycloak authentication for Swagger UI generated by Quarkus.
This is my config in application.properties:

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.oauth2-redirect-url=http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme=oidc
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme-name=Keycloak
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.oidc-open-id-connect-url=http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
quarkus.swagger-ui.oauth2-redirect-url=http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui
```

And my REST Controllers are annotated like this:

```
@Path("/my-path")
@Authenticated
@SecurityRequirement(name = "Keycloak")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyController {

    @GET
    public List<MyObject> listAll() {
       // [...]
    }
}
```

Now when I click on the "Authorize" button in Swagger, **instead of being redirected to my Keycloak login page**, I get a popup with all the different Available authorizations:

[image]

I cannot use any of these since my Keycloak is **not allowing direct grants**.

How can I achieve a login with redirect? Is this even possible?

**Bonus question**: Why do the swagger properties show up as unused in IntelliJ?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All right, I found a way to make it work, **albeit with the implicit flow and a dedicated second (public) client** in Keycloak.

The Quarkus application.properties:

```
# Swagger
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme=oauth2-implicit
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme-name=Keycloak
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.oauth2-implicit-authorization-url=http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
quarkus.swagger-ui.oauth2-redirect-url=http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html
```

The redirect URL neeeded to be [oauth2-redirect.html](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/oauth2-redirect.html)

Now I only need to enter the client_id:

[image]

And then I am redirected to Keycloak, and then back to Swagger-UI.
Hope this helps anyone hoping to achieve the same